# Serve images via Cloudfront while using mod_pagespeed with Apache

Tags: amazon-s3, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed, webp

We have **mod_pagespeed** on Apache and filters like **convert_jpeg_to_webp**.

We would however, also like to add CDN to the website, especially for the images and javascript files, in order to further enhance the performance and the Pagespeed score for this website. However, once we enable CDN, **jpeg versions** of the image are delivered via the CDN. We would like, however, to get the webp versions of the images (which work totally as expected) like when CDN is not enabled.

For example, without cdn,  `www.domainname.com/assets/images/imagename.jpg.pagespeed.ce.fqqfe4pa.jpg`

is converted to

```
www.domainname.com/assets/images/imagename.jpg.pagespeed.ce.fqqfe4pa.webp
```

But with CDN enabled, we get something like this in return:

```
cdn.domainname.com/assets/images/imagename.jpg.pagespeed.ce.fqqfe4pa.jpg
```

Anyone maybe has a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you authorized your CDN domain? You can find further details here: https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/domains